# When does est go at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar-choice

How do i know when to put the latin word 'est' at the end of a sentence?
For example: Scintilla fessa est, Scintilla est femina
Why is 'est' in a different position in each of the above sentences.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, Latin verbs go at the end of the sentence, including the verb *sum*. (Traditionally, Latin has been considered a "SOV" (subject, object, verb) language, though scholars have recently cast doubt upon the necessity of that claim.)

Having said that, verb placement can vary freely, mostly for pragmatic reasons---say if you want to emphasise the verb by placing it at the beginning of the sentence, or if you are answering a question, etc.

- *Vēnistī herī? # Vēnī hodiē* ("Did you come yesterday? # I came today")

Other times you may wish to make explicit an attributive (rather than an existential) use of *sum*. Compare:

- *Magnus sōl est* ("The great sun exists / there is great sun")
- *Magnus est sōl* ("The sun is great.")

In subordination constructions (such as Accusative + Infinitive) the main verb position can vary as well. E.g. all of these are semantically equivalent, but vary pragmatically:

- *Vergilius dīcit poētam arma virumque cecinisse* ("Virgil says that the poet sung the arms and man")
- *Vergilius poētam arma virumque cecinisse dīcit*
- *Dīcit Vergilius poētam arma virumque cecinisse*, etc.

Comment: That Latin is an SOV language is highly questionable. The "general rule" is that word order in Latin is free. The verb can go pretty much anywhere you like.

Comment: @fdb Agreed. I modified the first sentence. Note however that many scholars have claimed that (see Spevak's discussion in the Introduction to *Constituent Order in Classical Latin Prose*, 2010, pp. 2–3). And a Pinkster has suggested, syntactically Classical Latin can be said to be a SOV language, thought pragmatically it can be SVO or OVS.